# set value of element

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create a new element and then set the value of the new element. Then add the element to div.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("Header");
var element =document.createElement("test");
var addel=x.appendChild(element)
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <h1>
    <img height="150" src="http://test.com/im.jpeg">
    <span>test</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

for instance, create a new element called "test" then add the element to div and set the value of test="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property to set the text:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("Header");
var element =document.createElement("test");
element.textContent = "1";
var addel=x.appendChild(element);
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <h1>
    <img height="150" src="http://test.com/im.jpeg">
    <span>test</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new element won't be recognised by the browser as html has fixed set of elements 
You perhaps need to use a text based element like span,p or you can simply set innerText of a block element like div to "1"
If you want to create your own elements You can refer here
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements
You can also extend existing elements to form new elements

Answer (score 0):

change the code with

```
var x = document.getElementById("Header");
var element =document.createElement("test");
element.setAttribute('value','1');
var addel=x.appendChild(element);
```